# Update a field with datatype array in mongoDB using mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongoDB document like this.

```
{
  name: xyz,
  age : 30,
  languages: ["english","french" ]
}
```

I know I cant update the whole value against languages field but I want to update/add one more language  (or push an element in that array). Is it possible to do that with Mongoose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it like:

```
YourModal.updateOne(
    { _id: idToUpdate },
    {
      $push: { languages: "Arabic" }
    }
  );
```